# In .NET , is it possible to apply try catch inside an event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, fingerprint

Im creating a system based on fingerprint recognition and for this reason I am doing a windows service , using DigitalPersona, which is a fingerprint reader.

This reader has many methods like onFingerGone, OnFingerTouch and others. This methods are events that are fired when the fingerprint reader is touched.
Everythig goes well until that part. But when there is no activity.... (i mean that when the fingerprint reader is not touched) throws an error in the console.

"The proccess  exited with code 0"

Please help.

Some details:
- using Visual Studio 2010 .Net 4

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Yes, try catch can be used inside an event handler, it is no different than a method.

Comment: Have you debugged to see which method is throwing the exception?

Comment: Sure you can. But I don't think that's the problem as you'd get an unhandled exception not a exit with code 0. That sounds like your application might be ending normally.

Comment: It is typical that `On*` methods are the code that raises the events, not event handlers. I don't know if that changes anything here though. We do need to

Comment: thanks for your answer Cyral... there is not relevant code because Im using a SDK and the code that are behind those events are called from and Interface....

Comment: thanks Matt ....Yes I have debbugged many times, but it is not clear what it means by that code 0. the real problem is that after that code is shown ,, the fingerprint reader does not longer work.. unless it is being restarted

Comment: thanks Enigmativity... the things is that as I mentioned ,I m doing a windows service, that s why want to have control over those events..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code 0 means that were no errors.

Using events (OnFingerGone, OnFingerTouch) means your application to *wait* for them. "The proccess exited with code 0" usually means that main thread (?) of your *console application* is done or that your WPF, WinForms, etc. application called something like this.Application.Close().

For example:

```
class Pseudocode {
    event EventHandler myEvent;

    int main(){
        myEvent += onMyEvent;
        //do work 1
        return 0;
    }

    void onMyEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e){
       //do work 2
    }
    //other methods and work
}
```

If amount of work in main() is small, application will be closed immediately.

In console application you can prevent this simply adding Console.ReadLine(); (before return 0; according to example), so your application will be waiting for "Enter" key.

In windowed application you need to look for manual exit calls or something like this because they are not known as "self-closable".

Comment: Thanks Rawnald Gregory.... but i cant see where the event is instanciated, because is an SDK ...and its methods are shown through an interface.